# textbox2 will auto generate time according to textbox1 to maintain 4 hours time slots between textbox1 and textbox2

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have got the following code for ... if in textbox1 the would be appear as 10:10:00 AM and in textbox2 the time will appear as in 4 hours time slots automatically as 06:10:01 AM ..if the textbox2 time will be 06:10:01 AM then MSg box will appear that "You can not registered to this site because the 4 hours time slot will be over "

```
Dim tb1Val As DateTime = #8:20:20 AM#
Dim beforeVal As New TimeSpan(3, 59, 59)
Dim tb2Val As DateTime = tb1Val.AddSeconds(-beforeVal.TotalSeconds)
```

Remember in textbox1 the time would be any .....and textbox2 will auto generate time according to textbox1 to maintain 4 hours time slots between textbox1 and textbox2

Comment: so what exactly is your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about something like

```
Dim tb1Date As Date = Date.Parse(TextBox1.Text)  ''# make sure that TextBox1 has a valid date input
Dim tb2Date As Date = Date.Parse(TextBox2.Text)  ''# make sure that TextBox2 has a valid date input

Dim Span As TimeSpan = tb2Date - tb1Date  ''# get the timespan between the two dates (later date first)

If (Math.Floor(Span.TotalHours) < 4 Then
    ''# You can not registered to this site because the 4 hours time slot will be over
Else
    ''# You're good to go!
End If
```